# sending buttons dont work in Whatsapp web js

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp

for some reason it doesn't want to send buttons, I looked it up online but didn't found help, here's my code:

```
const { Client, LocalAuth ,MessageMedia, Buttons } = require('whatsapp-web.js');

const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth()
});

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});


client.on('message', message => {
    console.log('message from', message.from)
    if (message.body === "!button") {

        let button = new Buttons('Button body',[{body:'bt1'},{body:'bt2'},{body:'bt3'}],'title','footer');
        client.sendMessage(message.from, button);

    }
});
 
client.initialize();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install using:

```
npm i github:pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js#fix-buttons-list
```

or

```
yarn add github:pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js#fix-buttons-list
```

Comment: sendmessage doesnot work with this

Comment: It has stopped working. Apparently, WhatsApp is reserving it for their API. However, when I use list sending or buttons in some clients like (web or iOS), sometimes it arrives but it's not predictable. For now, we need to avoid this.

Comment: Sending buttons not working using this

Answer (score 0):

-install Git Bash from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

-open CMD and write: 'npm install git+https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js#fix-buttons-list' in the project directory.

Don't forget call "Buttons" when you are  define module.
like this:

```
const { Client, LocalAuth  ,Buttons,List,MessageMedia} = require('whatsapp-web.js');
```

Comment: There was already an almost identical answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33486727)